# is it possible to stop the changing of value in list_y where list_y = list_x

Tags: python, list

I am two list with same value [6,1,2,3,4].After that i'am changing the first value of list_x as 0.But its also changing the list_y.

```
list_x = list_y = [6,1,2,3,4]

list_x[0] = 0 

print (list_y)

//output:[0,1,2,3,4]
```

is there any way to change the list_x alone?i need to change the value of only one list how can i do this?

Comment: try `listx = listy.copy()`

Comment: The main thing to understand is that you **don't** have two lists with same value. You have one list and two variables referencing it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using slicing:

```
list_x = [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]

list_y = list_x[:]  # Creates a copy of list_x

list_x[0] = 0

print(list_x)  #Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print(list_y)  #Output: [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: list_a = [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]

list_b = list(list_a)

print("Before")

print(list_a)
print(list_b)  

list_a[0] = 0

print("After")

print(list_a)
print(list_b)